# Openshift Prestashop 1.5.6 Performance Tuning

Tags: performance, openshift, prestashop

In the prestashop performance page, it offers caching with APC, memcached, File System, and XCache.  There's a warning about making sure the infrastructure contains one front-end server.  If not sure, ask your hosting company.  What's available and best here?

I'm currently using the free 3 gear set up. 1 small gear with PHP 5.4 and scaling turned on (minimum 1, maximum all available), 1 small gear for mysql 5.5.  the HA Proxy shows one of my gears as active/down (red) with 0 bytes of anything.  I'm assuming because I don't have the High Availability turned on correctly.  I'm getting page load times of 1.5 to 3 seconds on average.  I know the small gear is low cpu, but is that a normal response time?  How can I tune this to sub 1 with what I have?  I'd like to see the performance capabilities and scaling abilities before I kick over a CC to grab bigger gears and more of them.

Speaking of scaling I see this `The code in the git repository is copied to each new gear, but the data directory begins empty.` I just recently made some post_deploy hooks to symlink an images directory so that my git updates from my local machine didn't destroy custom uploads.  Am I going to have to switch to some kind of CDN? I believe I saw an option to set CDN servers in the application.

Thanks in advance,
Alan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prestashop is probably a pretty beefy application to run on a small gear, even with moving the database to it's own gear.  Your web gear would have to receive enough traffic to scale up to another web gear, but as long as you are just getting a few requests to it, it might respond slowly and not scale up.  For a few cents an hour, it might be worth spinning up a medium/large gear and checking it's performance.

As for the data directory symlink.  On a scaled application, anything you upload into your OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR will not be synced across gears that are spun up.  You might want to consider finding some kind of Amazon S3 plugin or similar.

Comment: I'm currently receiving 504 timeouts on a variety of pages from backend admin creation of new products to simple viewing of the home page.  Any ideas about what's causing the server to be held up?

Comment: You might check if you are going over your memory limits on your gear: https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1082-how-to-check-for-memory-limit-violations

Comment: Just for the sake of knowledge.  I just got done updating haproxy to poll a simple `up.html` file instead of the project root, and upped the memory_limit php ini to 256 and that combo so far has increased my responsiveness and stopped the counter on the memory fail count.